# How to fix 502 errors on my WordPress site hosted on Windows Azure that only occur when I update a post?

Tags: errors

I have a Wordpress site that is hosted on Windows Azure, with the database hosted separately. Every time I try to update a post I get a 502 error, specifically:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server.

The DB provider says everything is fine - does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this problem? Oddly enough - basic reads are fine - the error only occurs when I try to update a post.

Comment: It sounds like a db connection timeout ;-) Can you save other settings or pages without problems?

Comment: Nope - I can do reads, but no writes or edits.  Now that I think about it, I can only do http gets, not http posts.

Comment: Is your application set to 32 or 64 bits (see [here](http://www.lextm.com/2013/08/a-wordpress-on-windows-azure-web-site-502-issue-and-possible-fix/))

Comment: I just reset it to 32 bit - absolutely no change.

Comment: And you get the same for plain vanilla mysql update command via php without going through WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on failed request tracing, and saw many entries (not errors, but entries) for [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) (I have wordpress running as a subdirectory of my .net site).  Glimpse is not supposed to be running in production - but apparently it does.  When I removed Glimpse everything worked just fine.  Live and learn I guess.